# Is there any convenient way to run remote program on local data?

Tags: linux, networking, remote

I have two servers running Linux, namely *A* and *B*. There is a large amount of data on *A*, but I want to use the program *x* on *B* to process those data. It would be inefficient to transfer all data from *A* to *B*, while it is also annoying to solve all dependencies to get *x* working on *A*. Therefore, the best solution should be to fetch *x* and its library dependencies from *B* into memory of *A* and run *x* on *A* locally.

So I would like to ask, is there any convenient way or existing tool to execute a remote program to process local data?

My idea is to mount the root directory of *B* on *A* using tools like sshfs, bind mount the data directory into the root dir, and chroot into it. However, this is not very convenient and requires additional setup for file systems like `/proc`, `/dev`.

To be more clear, there are mainly three inconvenient aspects:

1. I need root permission on *A*, which is usually not granted for a typical user of a server.
2. I need to setup various kernel file systems in the mounted root dir of *B* on *A*, like `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev`. Running as root on a server also requires additional carefulness.
3. After chroot, my personal configurations on *A* are all replaced by those on *B*. I only want to use *x* to process my data and would like to stay in a familiar environment :)

BTW, I need chroot because I need to run program *x*, which is on *B*; I could not mount data directory in *A* onto *B* because I want to avoid transferring data; so I could only transfer program from *B* to *A*, and I need chroot because *x* needs different libraries which are not available on *A*.

Comment: How about `VFS`?

Comment: @SparKotॐ could you give more details? Do you mean chroot into a VFS? thanks:)

Comment: You could use samba or nfs

Comment: Did you try your own idea of mounting B:/ on A? What is so inconvenient about it?

Comment: Why would you need to `chroot` just to access the data? Just mount the directory that contains the data.

Comment: @terdon because I need to run program *x*, which is on *B*; I could not mount data directory in *A* onto *B* because I want to avoid transferring data; so I could only transfer program from *B* to *A*, and I need chroot because *x* needs different libraries which are not available on *A*

Comment: Ah, I see. Could you please [edit] your question and explain these constraints? Otherwise, what you're asking for doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am currently editing my question:) Why does not it make sense? I do not know whether any other guy has the same demand and actually implemented a simple tool. For example it could be implemented by hooking on open() and related syscalls and replace ELF read by remote content.

Comment: @grebneke I tried it and it works, but I want to seek a better solution:) please see my edit0

Comment: Could you create a FIFO or nc to do this?

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins could please explain a little further? Do you mean using them to transfer program?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to have `/proc` or `/dev` mounted for chroot to work - that depends on what the program in question does. If it only processes data and doesn't do any "dirty tricks" (like directly accessing hardware through `/dev`), all of these are avoidable. `mount --bind /proc /chroot/proc` doesn't seem to be something overwhelmingly complex to avoid it at all cost. You would need root privileges for that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only problem is shared libraries, then the simplest thing is to recompile the program with static linking, giving you one big executable which doesn't need any shared libraries.

Alternatively, you could find the shared libraries (with `ldd`) and copy them over. Use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (see the `ld.so` man page) to point the executable to the location of the shared libraries.